# Storing large dynamic database on ios device or just make rest api calls?

Tags: ios, database, rest

I am creating an app for an existing website. Website is similar to IMDB, Netflix so there is large database with film,actors,users,ratings etc. I am just wondering what would be more efficient way to access the data, should I store part of the film data in the local storage or relay entirely on Rest api calls to retrieve the data. Data is being updated quite often and I guess this would require update off the app local database on regular basis.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best approach for you is just to pull the data when needed. Each user only search for maximum 2-3 movies or so right? Because the data is updated in regular bases, so he could check out a movie (with ranks and such) and after 5 minutes the local data is no longer updated, so he will need to pull it again, so the best way I think is to grab the data each time.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use both method? When user request a specific information with REST api, store the data in the local storage. Just update the local data when the data on server side is updated.

Comment: There are 150,000 films with their rating,actors,description, etc. What would be point of storing any specific film info, as this can be updated at any time plus synchronization issues.